# Print between string and a number through multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to print the number `0123` which is located between a line of string and a line of a number

```
import re

s = """
test Code:
0123

1

text1 text2

   """

if re.findall(r'test Code:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*1)', s):

 test=re.findall(r'test Code:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*1)', s)

 print(test)
```

My code prints the output like this `( "0" )` which is wrong,I want my output to be like this `( "0123" )`

Comment: Maybe `test Code:\s*(\d+)` is enough? Else, get to the newline with `.*` and test for `\n` before `\s*1`:  `test Code:\s*(.*)(?=\n\s*1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.`test Code:\s*(.*?)(?=\s+1)`

"*" matches 0 or more ,"+" mathes 1 or more

Comment: "*" matches 0 or more ,"+" mathes 1 or more

Comment: update your answer with your comment. (From Review).

Answer (score 0):

You could capture your value without using a positive lookahead by matching the newline and the whitespace characters after the group.

```
test Code:\n\s*(\d+)\s*\n\s*1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EAt2V9/1)

If 1 should be between a line of string and an line of number only, you might use:

```
^test Code:\n\s*(\d+)\s*\n\s*1\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
^
[^\d\n]+[\r\n] # line without digits
(\d+)[\r\n]    # only digits in that line
\s+\d+         # whitespaces + digits
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/X1L89z/2/) (mind the verbose and the multiline flag).